# hello how to determine Punctuation characters using regex in vb.net?

Tags: regex, vb.net

i am still learning dekstop programming using vb.net
Now iam learning about regex pattern, i can determine capital letter using regex pattern "[A-Z]" and more. but how to determine Punctuation characters using regex pattern?

Punctuation characters :
!"#\$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>\?@[\]\^_`{\|}~

```
   Public Sub UniqueKeyCodeStrengthCalculator()
        If Regex.IsMatch(keycode, "[A-Z]") Then
            MsgBox("Contain Capital Letter")
        ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(keycode, "\d") Then
            MsgBox("Contain number")
        ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(keycode, "[a-z]") Then
            MsgBox("Contain Non-capital Letter")
        End If
    End Sub
```

thank you before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this regex:

```
[\W_0-9]
```

`\W` checks for all characters other that `a-z` `A-Z` and `_`.

The above regex will work.

Comment: `\W` doesn't contain also `[0-9]` .